# Peer-to-Peer communication in NLB cluster

Tags: networking, ip, windows-server-2008, session, load-balancer

I'm a system administrator at a library in Holland. Our personnel uses thin clients which are making a remote desktop session to our session servers. We have two session servers (Windows 2008 R2) configured in a NLB cluster. Both servers are virtualisized. One in **Hyper-V (RDS01)** the other one in **VMWare ESX (RDS03)**.

The NLB cluster is configured to work in unicast mode. Both servers in the NLB cluster have two network adapters. One for the NLB cluster and the other to use for Peer-to-Peer communication.

The problem we are having is that making a remote desktop session to our NLB cluster often **fails** (same error as trying to connect to a not existing IP or hostname). After some digging I found out that when I'm trying to view the cluster in NLB manager on RDS03 it often fails to "discover" RDS01. The other way around works just fine (from RDS01 to RDS03).

Picture 1 below shows the NLB Manager on RDS01 (**SUCCESS**).
[image: NLB Manager on RDS01]

Picture 2 below shows the NLB Manager on RDS03 (**FAIL**).
[image: NLB Manager on RDS03]

As you can see on the first picture I disabled the RDS03 in the NLB cluster. Only RDS01 is the active server in the NLB cluster. This **solves** the connection problem to the NLB cluster for now (so I assume the problem lies around the RDS03).

I learned the NLB Manager uses ICMP to "discover" other hosts in the cluster. So I decided to use a packet sniffer (Microsoft Network Monitoring) to inspect the packets being send out by the NLB Manager. And I noticed in the packet being send out by the RDS01 that it uses the IP address of the Peer-to-Peer adapter on the RDS03. In addition to that, the RDS03 **sometimes** uses the NLB cluster IP address of RDS01.

Below the packet details captured on the RDS01.

```
  Frame: Number = 2812, Captured Frame Length = 74, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[00-15-5D-63-97-23],SourceAddress:[00-15-5D-63-96-2B]
+ Ipv4: Src = 10.81.129.159, Dest = 10.81.129.161, Next Protocol = ICMP, Packet ID = 8406, Total IP Length = 60
+ Icmp: Echo Request Message, From 10.81.129.159 To 10.81.129.161
```

Next, the packet details captured on the RDS03. When the NLB Managers sends out this package the discovery fails.

```
  Frame: Number = 211, Captured Frame Length = 74, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[02-BF-0A-51-81-A5],SourceAddress:[00-15-5D-63-97-23]
+ Ipv4: Src = 10.81.129.161, Dest = 10.81.129.167, Next Protocol = ICMP, Packet ID = 11326, Total IP Length = 60
+ Icmp: Echo Request Message, From 10.81.129.161 To 10.81.129.167
```

As last the packet details captured on the RDS03. When the NLB Manager sends out this package the discovery is successful.

```
  Frame: Number = 2095, Captured Frame Length = 74, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[00-15-5D-63-96-2B],SourceAddress:[00-15-5D-63-97-23]
+ Ipv4: Src = 10.81.129.161, Dest = 10.81.129.159, Next Protocol = ICMP, Packet ID = 21180, Total IP Length = 60
+ Icmp: Echo Request Message, From 10.81.129.161 To 10.81.129.159
```

Below the IP configuration for the NLB cluster and its servers.

**10.81.129.165** ... *NLB cluster IP*

**10.81.129.167** ... *NLB IP for RDS01*

**10.81.129.169** ... *NLB IP for RDS03*


**10.81.129.159** ... *IP RDS01 (second NIC for Peer-to-peer)*

**10.81.129.161** ... *IP RDS03 (second NIC for Peer-to-peer)*

Why is the RDS03 using the NLB cluster IP of RDS01? And why does it also uses the peer-to-peer IP of RDS01? What is causing this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: I found the cause of the inconsitent behavior. Apparently the NLB Manager uses the hostnames in the discovery proces. When our DNS server replies with the IP addresses of the RDS03 the IP adress order differences. If the NLB IP for RDS01 is first the discovery fails. When the IP RDS01 (second NIC for Peer-to-peer) is first the discovery succeeds. I´m also unable to ping NLB IP for RDS01 from RDS03.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was in the DNS lookup. After I cleared the DNS cache on the RDS03 (where the inconsistent behavior occured).

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

I did a cluster refresh on the RDS03 NLB Manager and noticed that it did a DNS lookup for RDS01. Now I knew for sure the NLB Manager was using hostnames to communicate. The DNS server responded with the two following IP addresses:

10.81.129.159 ... **IP RDS01** (second NIC for Peer-to-peer)
10.81.129.167 ... **NLB IP for RDS01**

Everytime the discovery of RDS01 failed the **NLB IP of RDS01** was the first IP of the DNS lookup reply. And everytime the discovery succeeded the **IP RDS01** was first.

After removing the **NLB IP of RDS01** DNS record from the DNS server the problem was solved. Now I only had to make sure the NLB IP addresses wouldn't register itself at the DNS server anymore. This was a setting in the TCP/IP protocol of the NLB NIC. See the image below.

[image: Don't register IP at DNS server]